# How to strip quotation marks from beginning and end of list

Tags: python, list

My list is not functioning properly because it is created as `["'carrots, 'tomatoes', 'lettuce'"]` rather than `['carrots, 'tomatoes', 'lettuce']`

I have a text file with `'carrots, 'tomatoes', 'lettuce'` written on one line, and this is how I am writing it into my list:

```
veggie_list =[]
x = open('veggies.txt','r')
for item in x:
    veggie_list.append(item)
```

Comment: That file format isn't easy to parse. You should use an established format for storing lists of items in text files, e.g.: JSON, YAML, CSV, and then use the appropriate decoding library to simply parse those into a Python list. What you have is neither here nor there.

Comment: In your script, x is going to be an array, and each item in the array is going to be a line in your file. You bring in this line, and then append it to the veggie_list array whole. You need to split this line and then append each item to veggie_list separately. See @abhiarora 's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Assuming you have multiple lines in your text file):

```
veggie_list = []
with open('veg.txt','r') as x:
    for item in x:
        veggie_list.extend(item.replace("'", "").split(','))

print(veggie_list)
```

Outputs:

```
['carrots', ' tomatoes', ' lettuce']
```

If you are only interested in the first line of your text file:

```
veggie_list = []
with open('veg.txt','r') as x:
    veggie_list = x.read().replace("'","").split(',')

print(veggie_list)
```

One Liner in Python using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
with open('veg.txt','r') as x:
    print([j for i in x for j in i.replace("'","").split(',')])
```

**EXPLANATION (For the first code):**

You need to first remove the single quote marks from the line you have read (`"'carrots', 'tomatoes', 'lettuce'"`) from the file. You can use [replace()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method of `str` object. This method returns a copy of modified string and it doesn't change the original string.

After that, you should be left with str `"carrots, tomatoes, lettuce"`. Now, I have used [split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method to divide the whole string into individual strings using `","` as delimiter.

This method returns a list `['carrots', ' tomatoes', ' lettuce']`.

Comment: A comment would be helpful along with the downvote to rectify my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

You inserting the String "'carrots, 'tomatoes', 'lettuce'". What I think you want to do is:

```
text = x.read()
text = text.replace("'","")
enter code here
veggie_list = text.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list into the string and replace " with space then use **eval** it will return you list

```
veggie_list =[]
x = open('veggies.txt','r')
for item in x:
    veggie_list.append(item)
veggie_list = eval(str(veggie_list).replace('"',''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, but it depends and the way that your text file is written:

```
veggies = []
veggie_list = []
x = open('veggies.txt','r')
for item in x:
    veggie.append(item)
for i in veggies:
    veggie_list.append(i)
```

This is probably that case. Your outer parentheses might signal that `["'carrots, 'tomatoes', 'lettuce'"]` is probably just one item inside the list. If you iterate it twice, it might work. Hope it helps